# Has there been a reputation recalc?

Tags: support, reputation

I'm pretty sure I was on 2467 rep yesterday. Today I am on 2436. I don't see any obvious changes in my accepted answers etc. Anyone else experience something like this?

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer. Apparently, reputation has [been recalculated globally across all sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80862/sudden-sharp-drop-in-reputation-find-out-reason-recalc/80865#80865). I've also raised a feature request on meta [asking that users be notified in future](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80890/please-notify-us-when-a-reputation-recalc-occurs).